# Laravel groupBy throws strict mode error when doing query

Tags: php, laravel

In my Laravel 9 project I have a model called `UptimeCheck` which contains several columns, of which I'm grabbing the following in my query:

- event
- response_time

I need to present a sum of all **down** events, **up** events and an average response time for the grouped **check_date** period.

Right now, when I even try to do a `groupBy`, Laravel's strict mode throws an error which prevents me from performing the query, if I remove all of my `where` clauses then the error goes away and the grouping works, but I need these for my query.

Here's my current starting attempt:

```php
UptimeCheck::where('user_id', 1)
            ->where('monitor_id', 1)
            ->where('checked_at', '>=', '2023-01-01 00:00:00')
            ->where('checked_at', '<=', '2023-01-31 23:59:59')
            ->orderBy('checked_at', 'asc')
            ->select('event', 'response_time', DB::raw('DATE(checked_at) as check_date'))
            ->groupBy('check_date')
            ->get();
```

For example, this is what my query data might look like

| **event** | **response_time** | **check_date** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| up | 100 | 2023-01-31 |
| up | 200 | 2023-01-31 |
| down | 400 | 2023-01-31 |
| up | 100 | 2023-01-30 |

What is my query missing for this behaviour to work?

Comment: What is the error? Usually this gives the error that you cannot select columns that aren't included in the group by. You can use aggregate functions to get the data you want. It looks like you should group by `check_date` _and_ `event` and then add `COUNT(*)` to get the number for each event on each date. You can also use `AVG(response_time)` to get the average response time for each event each day.

Comment: can you check your database side has a sql_mode=only_full_group_by